# Unloading a form in Excel VBA doesn't seem to work

Tags: excel, vba

It is possible I don't understand what "Unload" does but reading the help regarding the unload statement, it says that the form is removed from memory.  This tells me that the next time I Load the form using the "Load formname" statement, it should go thru the "Userform_Initialize" event again.  It does not. What am I missing?  Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting -- I was able to reproduce the behavior that you mentioned and also found it somewhat surprising. At first I thought it might be a bug which had something to do with potential time gaps between when a form is unloaded and when the memory is actually reclaimed, but then I consulted "VB & VBA in a Nutshell" (a book worth its weight in gold if you are a VBA programmer) and looked up the unload statement and came across:

> > > When you unload a form from memory, only the form window and controls are unloaded; the code attached to a form and controls within the from module remain in memory

All of which sounds like it is closer to `Hide` then the name would suggest. Evidently enough remains loaded in the background that `Initialize` is not retriggered when the form is reloaded by the load statement.

The simple workaround -- don't load userforms. Rather than launching them with code that looks like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Load UserForm1
End Sub
```

Use:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Showing the form will trigger the initialize event, even after the form has been unloaded. Interestingly enough, The book I quoted earlier was printed in 1998 and in its entry on the Load statement mentioned that `.Show` was the more modern way of displaying userforms. Unless you have some strong reason to use `Load`, I would recommend sticking with `Show`.